# ATI CCC on Windows: How to save settings?

Tags: windows-7, amd-radeon, display-settings

I use my laptop and a desktop display. When I start my laptop, I see the boot procedure on both screens. Then I get extended desktop. Why? I set it up like:
1: Primary: xy desktop display 1920x1080@59hz.
2: Secondary: laptop: disabled.

Why 59Hz? With 60Hz it'll make a distorted look on my display and "it's not just me". Basically you have to set it 59Hz to make it report 60Hz. Well.. funny stuff, nevermind.

So I want to save this and apply every time it boots. (Until it detects that the display setup changed.)

Is there a way?

VGA: ATI Radeon 3650HD
Driver: 10.6 official, Windows x64 version.

Comment: I can edit the "angriness" away if you want a calmer, objective question. Your preference.

Comment: Of course you can remove my rant.. guess the fanboys will spare mah life.. >.> :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People hate ATI software so much, that somebody wrote a replacement.

ATI Tray Tools http://www.guru3d.com/article/ati-tray-tools-/ .  It's free, it seems to actually work and not get in the way.

It's not a direct answer, but I gave up on CCC.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post this a comment but i guess i dont have enough rep on SU yet, anyways..

Doesnt ATI CCC have Profiles which will accomplish what you are looking for? My home desktop only has one driver but i have several profiles and although i dont have access to it right now, it always defaults to the one that i want (So i assume you can specify that somewhere?)

Comment: Oh that's what I need. The CCC is just so logical I couldn't manage to find it. (First: Why do I have to switch between basic and advanced? If I want to set my display output/etc, I have to use Basic and that wizard (where I cant set freq). Why? :/ Second: Why the Cancel and Apply button keeps blinking?! Oo)